# How to express a group suggestion? "I would like for us all to ..."

Tags: writing-style, letter-writing

I am writing an email to my work colleagues regarding a current project. I am the lead for the project, and also one of the workers. I want to describe an activity that I think the whole group should take part in, but I am not in a position to say "do it this way", and even if I was, that's not how I would want to act. What is the best way to express this idea?

My current draft reads as follows, but I don't think it sounds right:

> I would like for us all to *X*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Let's do *X*.
- How about we do *X*?
- I think it'd be a good idea to do *X*.
- *X* is a good option, don't you think?

I hope one of those helps. It's hard for me to understand what sentiment exactly you're trying to express, but I understand why you'd want to be vague.

Comment: "How about you all do X" seems to imply you're going to offload the work to your team and don't want to do the work yourself; How about "How about we do X?"?

Comment: Good suggestion.

Comment: @e.James You're welcome. Which one did you go with in your e-mail?

Comment: I chose "I think it would be a good idea to X" based on your third option.

Answer (score 2):

"I would like us all to *X*" is how I would write it. The "for" really isn't necessary.

Comment: Thank you. I think that explains why my original sentence sounded wrong.